# Stan vs PYMC3 for Discrete Mixture Models

Tags: bayesian, pymc3, mcmc, stan, pystan

I am studying zero-inflated count temporal data. I have built a `stan` model that deals with this zero-inflated data with an `if` statement in the `model` block. This is as they advise in the Stan Reference Guide. e.g.,

```
model { 
   for (n in 1:N) { 
      if (y[n] == 0) 
         target += log_sum_exp(bernoulli_lpmf(1 | theta), bernoulli_lpmf(0 | theta) + poisson_lpmf(y[n] | lambda));
      else
         target += bernoulli_lpmf(0 | theta) + poisson_lpmf(y[n] | lambda);
   } 
}
```

This `if` statement is clearly necessary as Stan uses NUTS as the sampler which does not deal with discrete variables (*and thus we are marginalising over this discrete random variable instead of sampling from it*). I have not had very much experience with `pymc3` but my understanding is that it can deal with a Gibbs update step (to sample from the discrete bernoulli likelihood). Then conditioned on the zero-inflated value, it could perform a Metropolis or NUTS update for the parameters that depend on the Poisson likelihood.

**My question is:** Can (*and if so how can*) `pymc3` be used in such a way to sample from the discrete zero-inflated variable with the updates to the continuous variable being performed with a NUTS update? If it can, is the performance significantly improved over the above implementation in `stan` (which marginalises out the discrete random variable)? Further, if `pymc3` can only support a Gibbs + Metropolis update, is this change away from NUTS worth considering?

Comment: Yes, PyMC3 can block update continuous and discrete parameters to provide discrete sampling. The only problem is that it will be *slower* and *less accurate* and *less robust*.  Marginalizing is almost always a win for efficiency/mixing due to the Rao-Blackwell theorem and for accuracy by working in expectation.  This is explained with an example in the Stan user's guide chapter on latent discrete parameters (the change-point model is also available in PyMC3).  So if you can marginalize in PyMC3 (or BUGS or JAGS), that'll be a big win for efficiency and accuracy.

Comment: Thanks very much Bob. I was not aware of the ties to Rao-Blackwell. I'll work though that to understand more.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the theorem says that working in expectation is more efficient.   By marginalizing out the discrete parameters, you work in expectation.